# Leaflet :- Different size circle on different locations on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js for creating a fix sized circle around marker on mouseover event and removing the same circle on mouseout event. I am providing a fixed radius i.e (10000) to create a same size circle around every marker but the circles are getting created with different sizes.

On mouse over I wrote the following :--

```
cir = L.circle([ lat, lng ], 1000000);  /*Where lat,lng are the position of currently drawn marker*/
cir.addTo(map);
```

Is there any formula or approach to calculate the radius by using lat,lng so that I can draw a same sized circle around my markers anywhere in map???

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or plunker that shows the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Hi @pk ,I have created a fiddle. Please check. Try to draw the markers on different locations. Even if I provided the same radius the circles are getting created with different sizes. I used circleMarker also /*Commented code*/  but the circleMarker size remains constant even after zoom in - zoom out. I want circle to be increased and decreased on zoom-in zoom-out (Circle covered area should be consistent on map).  Link :    http://jsfiddle.net/kamet4u/88bdrzkr/

Comment: I resolved the issue by myself by using circlemarker and adjusting the radius according to the zoom levels.